# MVC access client side printers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, silverlight

In my MVC5 intranet application, I need to give, for some users, the possibility to print badges. The special printers for the badges are installed in the user's PCs.

How can I access this printers?

I made some research on the web, and honestly I did not understand what is the state-of-the-art better solution (Silverlight, WCF service, ...).

Answer (score -1):

if your are looking to change the default printer or print automatically to current printer it is not possible from a web browser for security reasons.

even if it is in an intranet